# Why won't my subscribe trigger and execute on my observable method?

Tags: angular, observable, publish-subscribe

So I've got the (simple) following:

```
$this.getAllContentTypes().subscribe((res) => {
  console.log(Date.now() + ' - Subscribed, data loaded, calling router...');
});
```

Here's my method:

```
public getAllContentTypes(): Observable<ContentType> {
    console.log(Date.now() + ' - Calling getallcontenttypes');

    const jsonStringified = JSON.stringify(json);

    this.contentTypeService.getAllContentTypes(jsonStringified).pipe(
      operators.tap(res => this.convertJsonResultToArrayCT(res)))
      .subscribe(res2 => this.storeInSessionStorage(res2, 'ContentTypes'));

    return from(this.contentTypeArray);
}
```

Why won't it log to console in my first subscribe?

Comment: Where does `contentTypeArray` come from? What does `this.contentTypeService.getAllContentTypes` return? 

If I recall correctly the `from()` method requires an `observable` input.

Answer (score 1):

Your `contentTypeService.getAllContentTypes` probably returns a Hot Observable but you implicitly expect a Cold Observable.

See [this article](https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339) for an explanation. Basically, only Cold Observables create values on subscription, like Angular's http service.